# Advanced Custom Field | Post Objects within a repeater dosen´t work

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I´m working with wordpress and Advanced Custom Field and I´m trying to display post objects in an acf repeater, but unfortunately it only outputs the first row of the repeater. Someone has an idea why?

Here is my Code:

```
<?php if( have_rows('repeater') ): ?>
<?php while( have_rows('repeater') ): the_row(); 
    // vars
    $repeater = get_sub_field('repeater'); ?>
    <?php $repeaterGroup = get_sub_field('repeater_group'); ?>
    <div class="box25-75">
        <div class="col col1">
            <?php $colLeft= $repeaterGroup['left_col']; ?>
            <div class="text">
                <p class="text-center">
                    E: <a href="mailto:<?php echo $colLeft['email']; ?>"><?php echo $colLeft['email']; ?></a><br />
                    T: <?php echo $colLeft['telefon']; ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col2">
            <div style="margin-top: 40px;">
                <?php
                  $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'html5-blank',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => '100',
                  );
                  $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                  if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
                          // Set variables
                          $title = get_the_title();
                          $description = get_the_content(); 
                          $field = get_field_object('autor');
                          $colors = $field['value'];
                          $date = get_the_date( 'd.m.Y' );
                          // Output
                          ?>
                            <?php // show something ?>
                            <?php $wp_query->reset_postdata(); ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I don't think you are resetting the postdata correctly. Should just be `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`

Comment: @disinfor 
I've tried it but the result is the same

Comment: Are you getting any post output? You said the first row of the repeater, but not sure if that includes the post output. Also, I would suggest not using `$wp_query` as your variable to hold the new query - as that's a global variable and may have conflicts.

Comment: @disinfor Hi thanks for your help. I found my problem. For some reason i had to change reset_postdata() with reset_query()

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. Instead of reset the post data, I had to reset de query. So I changed the line "$wp_query->reset_postdata();" with "wp_reset_query();"